# Calculate a percentage from a column in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the percentage of a column. I have real estate sales aggregated to the block group and I want to calculate the percentage of all sales per block group. I want to create the 'percent of sales' column in sql. 
Any help will be appreciated!

```
geoid     sales      percent of sales
  1       34            7.28
  2      256           54.82
  3       45            9.64
  4      117           25.05
  5        3            0.64
  6       12            2.57
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a SQL query using window functions:

```
select geoid, sales,
       sales * 100.0 / sum(sales) over ()
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple subquery and some maths to achieve this.

```
SELECT geoId, sales, (SUM(sales)* 100 / (SELECT SUM(sales) 
  FROM MyTable)) as Percentage
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY geoId, sales
```

Here's an example of it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e46d/7)